# Hypertreelist not firing when item selected

Tags: windows, wxpython

I am on a Windows machine, I am using WxPython Phoenix. I have a hypertreelist that should fire a function when an item is selected (or focused/clicked)...

```
import wx.lib.agw.hypertreelist as htl 

self.apps_tree = htl.HyperTreeList(self, -1,
                                size=wx.Size(width, height),
                                style=wx.TR_NO_BUTTONS | wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT | wx.TR_SINGLE | wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT | wx.TR_NO_LINES,
                                agwStyle=wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT | wx.TR_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT | wx.TR_NO_BUTTONS | wx.TR_NO_LINES | wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT)
self.apps_tree.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnAppSelected)
```

I've tried to append the Bind on self (wx.Panel), I tried to use other events such as EVT_TREE_ITEM_HYPERLINK, EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED but none worked. The code above works on Mac though...

The item not even gets colored... I have other elements on screen but as far as I can tell there is no overlaying...

Comment: Also having the issue with both agw.hyperTreeList and with gizmos.TreeListCtrl. Double-click events work (EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED) but not single-clicks (EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED). I tried the self.Layout() trick, but it didn't help. Might be due to the tree being buried in a simplebook page in a splitter window.

Comment: I was also missing the events even when including only the <tree>.Layout() call.  It started working after I added both:  <tree>.SetAutoLayout(True) and <tree>.Layout()

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue...

I manage to make this work using `self.Layout()` after adding all elements on screen